# Why does the loss of a neural net flat-line and then suddenly drop?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, gradient-descent

The loss graph for my neural net looks like this:

Blue is validation data loss and green is the training data loss.

[image]

As you can see, the loss remains almost flat for the first 600 epochs and then it suddenly drops. The validation loss and training loss also start to diverge just before the training data loss starts to drop.

Why does the loss stay flat for so long before suddenly dropping?

Comment: Please include a legend of what green/blue represent, and labels for the axes.

Comment: While I agree with that remark (as a good plotting practice), the context is enough to show that the y-axis is the loss, the x-axis the number of epochs, green is on the training set, and blue is on the validation set.

Comment: @Galen I said what legends are in the question. Did you read the question?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Agreed. Good plotting practices are what I am advocating for here.